# Hubbard & Hubbard: domain of $(1+x)^{1/x}$

Tags: limits, functions

On page 98 of Hubbard & Hubbard's *Vector Calculus, Linear Algebra, and Differential Forms [2nd Ed.]*, they say of

$$ f(x) = (1+x)^{1/x}, $$

that

> although we cannot evaluate the function at 0, the natural domain of the function includes $[-1,0) \cup (0, \infty)$, and 0 is in the closure of that set.
>
> **Footnote.** We say that the natural domain "includes" $[-1,0) \cup (0, \infty)$ because one might argue that -3 is also in the natural domain; every number, whether positive or negative, has a unique real cube root.

*(I don't think the footnote is relevant to my question.)*

I'm confused about the inclusion of -1 in the domain. Since

$$ f(-1) = (1 + (-1))^{1/-1} = 0^{-1} = \dfrac{1}{0} , $$

isn't $f$ undefined at $x = -1$? Shouldn't the natural domain be $(-1,0) \cup (0, \infty)$?

Comment: I agree with you. It seems like an oversight. The author was focused on making the point in the footnote about excluding $x$-values that make the base negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From page 92 of the latest edition of the book, Hubbard & Hubbard's Vector Calculus, Linear Algebra, and Differential Forms [5th Ed.]:

> For example, does it make sense to speak of
>   $$\lim_{x \to 0} (1+x)^{1/x}?$$
>   Yes; although we cannot evaluate the function at 0, the natural domain of the function includes $(-1,0) \cup (0,\infty)$, and 0 is in the closure of that set.

I excluded the footnote; it was longer than before, but again, it used $(-1,0) \cup (0,\infty)$ instead of $[-1,0) \cup (0,\infty)$. Therefore, I think we can safely say that the closed bracket in the 2nd edition is an error. The only thing that I still think is curious is that I can't find any mention of it in the [2nd edition errata](http://www.matrixeditions.com/errata%2Cnotes.SE.pdf).